# How do I make text with pixelated overlay (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<h1>` tag that I initially want to have a pixelated overlay; something like this:

[image]

And when I hover over it, I want it to fade-transition to make the actual text visible.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this with HTML and/or CSS?

I've tried with the CSS `text-shadow` property, but that only makes it blurry, not pixelated.

Comment: Please put in some code as [reprex] to prevent the question from being closed...

Comment: Are you wanting just any pixellated image to start with or do you want it to be related to the actual text characters so as you hover they gradually get clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You will only want to `transition` the properties concerned, because `all` can cause the transition to fail when a property cannot be animated.

I added a delay variation in the snippet that affects the `width` and `opacity` only.

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 40px;

    background: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-pixelated-pattern_1053-169.jpg") no-repeat;

    width: 480px; opacity: 1;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in, opacity 1s ease-in;
}

h1:hover::after {
    width: 0; opacity: 0;
    transition: width 1s ease-in, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<h1>Never gonna give you up</h1>
<!-- Never gonna let you dooown -->
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Disclaimer:

This is a modified version of @RockyBarua's post, but seriously changed to work with changing text, and it just has better pixilation and transition.

I don't think text pixelating is possible with CSS. The closest I've got are these:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var contentV = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML;
 // document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty("--content", "yay");
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].setAttribute('data-after', contentV);
}, 50);





<!-- Song Start -->

<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 3500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 5600);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 8700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 10800);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 12800);

<!-- Chorus End -->


setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We've known each other for so long";
}, 16800);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Your heart's been aching, but you're too shy to say it (say it)";
}, 20000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Inside, we both know what's been going on (going on)";
}, 24000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We know the game and we're gonna play it";
}, 27300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "And if you ask me how I'm feeling";
}, 30300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Don't tell me you're too blind to see";
}, 33300);


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 36000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 38000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 40100);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 43200);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 45300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 47300);

<!-- Chorus End -->


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 51400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 53400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 55500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 58600);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 60700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 62700);

<!-- Chorus End -->


setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We've known each other for so long";
}, 67700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Your heart's been aching, but you're too shy to say it (say it)";
}, 71000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Inside, we both know what's been going on (going on)";
}, 74500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We know the game and we're gonna play it";
}, 78000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling";
}, 81000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Gotta make you understand";
}, 84000);


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 86100);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 88100);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 90200);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 93300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 95400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 97400);

<!-- Chorus End -->


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 102400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 104400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 106500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 109600);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 111700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 113700);

<!-- Chorus End -->


setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "...";
}, 117700);


<!-- Chorus Repeat Infinite -->

setTimeout(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
    }, 1500);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
    }, 3500);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
    }, 5600);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
    }, 8700);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
    }, 10800);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
    }, 12800);
    
  }, 13800);
  
}, 120700);

<!-- Chorus Repeat Infinite End -->

<!-- Song End -->
```

```css
:root {
    --content: "yay";
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    font: 60px;
  }
  h1::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: attr(data-after);
    background: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-pixelated-pattern_1053-169.jpg') repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  h1:hover::after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Text Here</h1>
```

One with background clip:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var contentV = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML;
 // document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty("--content", "yay");
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].setAttribute('data-after', contentV);
}, 50);





<!-- Song Start -->

<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 3500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 5600);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 8700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 10800);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 12800);

<!-- Chorus End -->


setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We've known each other for so long";
}, 16800);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Your heart's been aching, but you're too shy to say it (say it)";
}, 20000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Inside, we both know what's been going on (going on)";
}, 24000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We know the game and we're gonna play it";
}, 27300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "And if you ask me how I'm feeling";
}, 30300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Don't tell me you're too blind to see";
}, 33300);


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 36000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 38000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 40100);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 43200);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 45300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 47300);

<!-- Chorus End -->


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 51400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 53400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 55500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 58600);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 60700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 62700);

<!-- Chorus End -->


setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We've known each other for so long";
}, 67700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Your heart's been aching, but you're too shy to say it (say it)";
}, 71000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Inside, we both know what's been going on (going on)";
}, 74500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "We know the game and we're gonna play it";
}, 78000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling";
}, 81000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Gotta make you understand";
}, 84000);


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 86100);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 88100);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 90200);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 93300);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 95400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 97400);

<!-- Chorus End -->


<!-- Chorus Start -->

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
}, 102400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
}, 104400);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
}, 106500);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
}, 109600);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
}, 111700);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
}, 113700);

<!-- Chorus End -->


setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "...";
}, 117700);


<!-- Chorus Repeat Infinite -->

setTimeout(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna give you up";
    }, 1500);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna let you down";
    }, 3500);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna run around and desert you";
    }, 5600);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna make you cry";
    }, 8700);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna say goodbye";
    }, 10800);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you";
    }, 12800);
    
  }, 13800);
  
}, 120700);

<!-- Chorus Repeat Infinite End -->

<!-- Song End -->
```

```css
:root {
    --content: "yay";
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    font: 60px;
  }
  h1::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: attr(data-after);
    background: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-pixelated-pattern_1053-169.jpg') repeat;
    background-size: 40%;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  h1:hover::after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Text Here</h1>
```